# How to apply ng-change for disabled field?

Tags: java, angularjs

Here I have One field which is disabled. It contains calculation of `X` field. Whenever x field changed the calculation of disabled field will be changed and When disabled field changed then I want to calculate `Y` filed.
So I applied ng-change to disabled field.But it is not working. Is ng-change will work for disabled field, If not is there any alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it won't work. Make it read only but not disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngChange directive doesn't work on disable/readonly inputs, because it's only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model. So, since you're changing the value programmatically and not typing anything to this model, it doesn't calls ngChange. You can use $scope.$watch.

**Update**

**Html**

Suppose you want to call total1 function if number1 changed. Eg:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number1" ng-readonly>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.$watch('number1', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        // Call total1 function
         total1();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please give me a small example for '$scope.$watch'

Comment: Just watch X model. $scope.$watch('X', function (val) {  Y = val  });

Comment: I just updated my answer. You need to have model for the comparison of old value and new value. Put ng-model="something" in your input text.

Comment: great explanation