# How to apply $scope.$watch to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

reff:-[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478226/how-to-apply-ng-change-for-disabled-field/41478394#41478394)

`<input type="text" readonly="readonly" ng-change="total1()">` this is my disabled field. And when disabled field changed then `total1()` need to call.

How to apply $scope.$watch to that textbox.

Comment: first of all you cant use ng-change without ng-model on the element and in the link everything is clear......i would like to know what you havent understand in that??

Answer (score 0):

- You should add `ng-model` and `ng-disable` directive in your textbox and also remove `ng-change`.

  `<input type="text" ng-disable="disableProperty" readonly="readonly" ng-model="ModelProperty">`
- and you should call the `ng-disable` object in the scope.

Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch("disableProperty", function(newValue, OldValue) {
    if(newValue != OldValue)
    {
       //if(newValue == false)// check true or false if you want which time this  function will fire
        //{
           $scope.total1()
       //}
     }
});
```